# Connection to Analysis Services from Excel error

Tags: excel, ssas

I have excel 2016 installed on Windows 2010. I am trying to connect to Sql Server Analysis Services 2000 installed on Windows 2003 to retrieve data. I get the following message "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".
When I try to connect from excel 2003 installed on Windows 2003 or from excel 2010 installed in Win7 it is ok.
In all 3 situations I use Windows Authentication with the same domain user login on the Windows!!!

UPDATE
When I try to connect from Sql Server Managent Studio I recieve the same error but with more details:

===================================

Cannot connect to MyServerName.

===================================

A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenConnectionAndCheckIfSessionTokenNeeded(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Platform.Security.TransparentUserContext.ExecuteInUserContextImpl[TResult](Func`1 action) at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Platform.Security.UserContext.ExecuteInUserContext[TResult](Func`1 action)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectXmla()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.50.19:2383 (System)

---

Program Location:

at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(IConnectivityOwner owner, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)

Comment: And are you connecting from/to the same machines in all cases, with the same firewall configuration? The error message simply implies SSAS is not reachable (normally listening on port 2383); no authentication is involved at this step yet.

Comment: Yes. The target/server machine is the same.  3 different clients (excel/windows) on the same network/domain each time login with the same network admin domain account using Windows Authentication.

Comment: So the target's the same, but I take it the client machines are not. Try a simple `ping` to the destination host. Also try `http://<host>:2383` from a browser -- this connection will of course not succeed since SSAS doesn't speak HTTP, but it should show if the port is reachable from the client. (Normally I'd suggest using `telnet`, but that's installed less and less on machines these days.)

Comment: Also the same problem from again excel 2016 but installed in Windows 2016! It seems that excel 2016 has the problem

Comment: Ping is ok. Telnet ok. The machine is reachable.